# Getting the latest value from a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with following structure

```
Debtor ID    | AccountRating    | AccountRatingDate   | AmountOutstanding    |AmountPastDue
John Snow      Closed             2017-03-01            0                     0
John Snow      Delayed            2017-04-22            2000                  500
John Snow      Closed             2017-05-23            0                     0
John Snow      Delayed            2017-07-15            6000                  300
Sarah Parker   Closed             2017-02-01            0                     0
Edward Hall    Closed             2017-05-01            0                     0
Douglas Core   Delayed            2017-01-01            1000                  200
Douglas Core   Delayed            2017-06-01            1000                  400
```

What I want to achieve is

```
Debtor ID    | Incidents of delay    | TheMostRecentOutstanding    | TheMostRecentPastDue
John Snow      2                       6000                          300
Sarah Parker   0                       0                             0
Edward Hall    0                       0                             0
Douglas Core   2                       1000                          400
```

Counting incidents of delay is pretty straightforward

```
df_account["pastDuebool"] = df_account['amtPastDue'] > 0
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index = df_account.groupby("Debtor ID").groups.keys())
new_df['Incidents of delay'] = df_account.groupby("Debtor ID")["pastDuebool"].sum()
```

I am struggling with extracting the most recent amonts outstanding and pastdue. My code is like this

```
new_df["TheMostRecentOutstanding"] = df_account.loc[df_account[df_account["AccountRating"]=='Delayed'].groupby('Debtor ID')["AccountRatingDate"].idxmax(),"AmountOutstanding"]
new_df["TheMostRecentPastDue"] = df_account.loc[df_account[df_account["AccountRating"]=='Delayed'].groupby('Debtor ID')["AccountRatingDate"].idxmax(),"AmountPastDue"]
```

But they return Series with all NaN values. Please help me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.sort_values('AccountRatingDate')\
  .query('AccountRating == "Delayed"')\
  .groupby('Debtor ID')[['AccountRating','AmountOutstanding','AmountPastDue']]\
  .agg({'AccountRating':'count',
        'AmountOutstanding':'last',
        'AmountPastDue':'last'})\
  .reindex(df['Debtor ID'].unique(), fill_value=0)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Debtor ID  AccountRating  AmountOutstanding  AmountPastDue
0     John Snow              2               6000            300
1  Sarah Parker              0                  0              0
2   Edward Hall              0                  0              0
3  Douglas Core              2               1000            400
```

Details:

- First sort dataframe by AccountRatingDate to get the last date as the
  last record.
- Filter the dataframe to only those with AccountRatings equal to
  'Delayed'
- Groupby Debtor ID with columns to aggregate, then use agg    with a
  dictionary to indicate how to aggregate each column
- Reindex with the unique values of Debtor ID to fill zero for those
  without any delays
- And, reset index.

And, you can do column renaming with `rename` and a dictionary:

```
df.sort_values('AccountRatingDate')\
  .query('AccountRating == "Delayed"')\
  .groupby('Debtor ID')[['AccountRating','AmountOutstanding','AmountPastDue']]\
  .agg({'AccountRating':'count',
        'AmountOutstanding':'last',
        'AmountPastDue':'last'})\
  .reindex(df['Debtor ID'].unique(), fill_value=0)\
  .rename(columns={'AccoutRating':'Incidents of delay', 
                   'AmountOutstanding':'TheMostRecentOutstanding',
                   'AmountPastDue':'TheMostRecentPastDue'})\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Debtor ID  AccountRating  TheMostRecentOutstanding  TheMostRecentPastDue
0     John Snow              2                      6000                   300
1  Sarah Parker              0                         0                     0
2   Edward Hall              0                         0                     0
3  Douglas Core              2                      1000                   400
```

Comment: Good answer, great explanation! I certainly learned from this.

Comment: @d_kennetz Thank you, sir.  I upvoted your answer as well.  I like your approach too.

Answer (score 2):

This will sort the values by date (keeping the last value), sum your boolean 'True' values, and then drop duplicates in the index. It will then get rid of the columns you don't want and give you your 'new_df':

```
df = pd.read_table('fun.txt')
df['pastDuebool'] = df['AmountPastDue'] > 0

df = df.set_index('DebtorID').sort_values('AccountRatingDate')
df['Incidents of Delay'] = df.groupby('DebtorID')['pastDuebool'].sum()
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]

df = df.drop(['pastDuebool', 'AccountRatingDate', 'AccountRating'], axis=1)
new_df = df.rename(columns={'AmountOutstanding':'TheMostRecentOutstanding',
                            'AmountPastDue':'TheMostRecentPastDue'})

print(new_df)
```

output:

```
                 AmountOutstanding  AmountPastDue  Incidents of Delay
DebtorID
SarahParker                  0              0                 0.0
EdwardHall                   0              0                 0.0
DouglasCore               1000            400                 2.0
JohnSnow                  6000            300                 2.0
```